# How to create nested loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, ipython, nested-loops

I have a list of results from doing

```
For user in users:
   print dct(user)
```

and the result is

```
user4 -> [diving]; user2->[swimming]; user6->[diving,swimming,running]; user8 ->[diving,swimming,skating]
```

and I'm now trying to create a nested loop to compare each user with other users (for example, compare user4 with user2, user6, user8 then compare user2 with user6, and user8)

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: I got rid of my nested loop and I tried importing itertools. Then I did "itertools.combinations(user,dct) and printed user. 

user is our imput file and dct is our dictionary of each user. However, I am getting an error message that says an integer is required.

Comment: It's simple! You just need put one loop to another :D

Answer (score 0):

```
# loop through each user in the users list
# use enumerate() so we also get the user's position in the list
for position,user1 in enumerate(users):
    # loop through each user in the remainder of the users list
    for user2 in users[position + 1:]
        compare_users(user1, user2)
```